# JavaFx custom ListCell is empty

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to create a very simple custom `ListCell` for a JavaFX `Listview`. When running the Application there are Items in the `ListView` without any content. They're clickable but empty. Like following image shows:

[image]

I'm using JDK 12 and a Maven JFX Archetype(archetype-artifactid:javafx-archetype-fxml, groupid:org.openjfx) based setup. I followed a guide called "Turais Custom ListCell".

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

private static Scene scene;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}

private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

PrimaryController.java

```
public class PrimaryController implements Initializable {

ObservableList<Student> students;

@FXML
private ListView<Student> listView1;

@FXML
private void switchToSecondary() throws IOException {
    App.setRoot("secondary");
}

public PrimaryController(){
    super();
    students = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   students.add(new Student());

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    listView1.setItems(students);
    listView1.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Student>, ListCell<Student>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Student> call(ListView<Student> listView) {
            return new StudentListViewCell();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Primary.fxml

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="257.0" prefWidth="230.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.test.PrimaryController">    
   <children>
      <Label text="Primary View" />
      <Button fx:id="primaryButton" onAction="#switchToSecondary" text="Switch to Secondary View" />    
      <ListView fx:id="listView1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
   </VBox>
```

ListCell.fxml

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label  fx:id="label1" layoutX="293.0" layoutY="190.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

StudentListViewCell.java

```
public class StudentListViewCell extends ListCell<Student> {

@FXML
private Label label1;

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPane;

private FXMLLoader mLLoader;

@Override
protected void updateItem(Student student, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(student, empty);

    if(empty || student == null) {

        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);

    } else {
        if (mLLoader == null) {
            mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ListCell.fxml"));
            mLLoader.setController(this);

            try {
                mLLoader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        label1.setText("rightText");


        setText(null);
        setGraphic(anchorPane);
    }

}
```

}

Student.java

```
public class Student {
private String name;



public Student(String name){
    this.name = name;

}
```

}

I'd expect a single `ListCell` which has a label in the middle with "rightText" written in it. But it seems like my custom listcell is not even rendered. Any suggestions?

Comment: try give an id to your anchorPane in the FXML file then give the same on to your field @FXML

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah the simple things that make you go "Ohh" . Finally it worked thanks a lot

Comment: This is a lot of unnecessary overhead for a ListCell implementation.  ListCell already extends Labeled, so it has its own text property.  There is no need for a new AnchorPane and Label.  Instead of using those, just call `this.setText("rightText");`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice VGR. I've read this in the official javadoc. I just put a label inside to simulate a custom element. This was only for testing purpose to break down the problem to it s bare bone. Just for clearing up if somebody else reads this and they only want text they should follow your advice =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your implementation appearing to be much more complex than it needs to be, your actual issue is a very simple one.

Your `ListCell.fxml` file does not assign an `fx:id` to your `AnchorPane`. Therefore, when you define it in your `StudentListViewCell.java` class, you're essentially creating a new `AnchorPane`, and one that does not contain your `Label`.

Simply changing your `ListCell.fxml` file and assigning the id will fix that issue:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label1" layoutX="293.0" layoutY="190.0" text="Label"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```